# Detecting popup window with ICS HttpCli or Indy components

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I friend of mine asked me if there is a way to detect a popup window when you use GET request.
Some sites show popup window for special info like  special discounts , free rewards etc...
At first I wanted to find answer for him but now I'm curious too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GET` request merely downloads the raw data for a given URL, nothing more. Popups occurs when a webbrowser processes the data and executes any script code that is contained in the HTML. If you are sending your own `GET` requests, then you would have to parse the HTML yourself and interpret the scripts yourself. Otherwise, load the URL into a `TWebBrowser` component and use its `OnNewWindow2` event to detect popups.

Comment: damn considering that twebrowser = IE , and IE is for me the worst browser, than nothing , but thanks for answer.